# 2D Arrays and adding them together in Assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I need to create a two dimensional array in my data segment and create a program that calculates the sum of each row and the sum of all rows combined in the array in two procedures using a loop and indirect addressing. Here's what I have so far. Each initialized byte array is a row.

```
    INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
array BYTE 11h, 43h, 21h, 65h, 10h
array_size = ($ - array)            ;array_size = 5
      BYTE 72h, 75h, 1Ah, 5Dh, 0FFh
      BYTE 0E4h, 0AFh, 33h, 3Dh, 0F6h
      BYTE 60h, 30h, 0AAh, 5Ah, 6Ah
      BYTE 0DFh, 0CAh, 4Bh, 4Fh, 1Ah

row_result BYTE 5 DUP(?)


.code
main PROC
    MOV EAX, 0
    MOV ECX, array_size
    MOV AL, [array+12]
    CALL DUMPREGS
    exit
main ENDP

row_sum PROC
;finish the code to sum up every row within the array and place them into row_result
row_sum ENDP

array_sum PROC
;finish the code to sum up the whole 2D array and place it into EAX
array_sum ENDP

END main
```

How do I create the loop to add each row individually then all rows as a whole?

Comment: Please specify the specific problem that you're encountered.

Comment: I'm having trouble creating the loop needed to add each row individually and moving it to an uninitialized array then all of the rows as a whole and moving that into EAX.

Comment: Can you write a loop in C or pseudo code?

Comment: Yes I'm currently learning C++ but I'm having a lot of trouble with learning x86 Assembly code.

Comment: Ok, what does the pseudo code look like?  Then all you have to do is decompose the pseudo code into individual piece parts and code those in assembly.  It is very hard to write algorithms from scratch in assembly when you're learning it, so start with C or pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

### How to add the elements of an array

1. Establish a pointer to the list of numbers
2. Clear some container to receive the sum
3. Load a counter with the number of items in the list
4. Load the number that the pointer points at
5. Add the value to the container
6. Advance the pointer
7. Repeat steps 4, 5, 6, and 7 for all items in the list

### In assembly (masm)

```
  mov   esi, offset array       ; 1
  xor   edx, edx                ; 2
  mov   ecx, array_size         ; 3
Again:
  movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]     ; 4    (*)
  add   edx, eax                ; 5
  inc   esi                     ; 6
  dec   ecx                     ; \ 7
  jnz   Again                   ; /
```

Because your *array* has 5 rows that are in fact 5 little arrays, you will have to repeat the above 5 times (using nested loops), each time storing the sum in the next available position in your *row_result* destination array (using another pointer like `EDI`).

> ```
> row_result BYTE 5 DUP(?)
> ```

You might want to enlarge the size here. I didn't add those numbers myself, but I think adding the numbers could quickly overflow the byte format.

> How do I create the loop to add each row individually **then all rows as a whole**?

Here you apply the same algorithm to the *row_result* array.

(*) Either find out or else decide for yourself whether the numbers in the array are to be considered signed or unsigned.

- If they are signed use `movsx eax, byte ptr [esi]`
- If they are unsigned use `movzx eax, byte ptr [esi]`

---

Feel free to post your next effort if it still doesn't work like it should...
Make a real effort though, it must be definitely more than what I have written today. And write comments so we can see if you understood what you wrote. Good luck.